# Interface Segregation Principle Problem where one interface inherits two interfaces that share the same parent

Tags: c#, typescript, solid-principles, interface-segregation-principle

I have an application with the following types setup and in use.

```
type CompanyFounder {
    name: string;   
    age: number;
    salary: number;
    sharesHeld: number;
    getReasonStartedCompany: string;
};

type NonExecDirector = {
    name: string;   
    age: number;
    sharesHeld: number;
    string[]: getExternalStuff;
};
```

I was tasked with adding a new type:

```
type Person = {
    name: string;   
    age: number;
};
```

I figured I could improve the code and reduce duplicating fields on related types using the interface segregation principle.
Here is what I came up with:

```
type Person = {
    name: string;   
    age: number;
};

interface Employee extends Person {
    salary: number;
}

interface Director extends Person {
    sharesHeld: number;
}

interface CompanyFounder extends Director, Employee {
    getReasonStartedCompany: string;
}

interface NonExecDirector extends Director {
    string[]: getExternalStuff;
}
```

However, I think I have a problem. The whole system works as it did before the change but I just want to check if there is actually a way around the fact that the Company founder is receiving `name` and `age` twice because it extends both Director and Employee.

Just to get people from the server-side/backend devs involved, here is the same problem in a C# example

```
public interface Person {
    string GetName();   
    int GetAge();
}

public interface Employee : Person {
    int GetSalary();
}

public interface Director : Person {
    int GetSharesHeld();
}

public interface CompanyFounder : Director, Employee {
    string GetReasonStartedCompany();
}

public interface NonExecDirector : Director {
    string[] GetExternalStuff();
}
```

So, problem is that the Company founder is receiving `GetName()` and `GetAge()` twice because it implements both Director and Employee.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Type/interface is just a contract, it doesn't implement anything. There's also no duplication here..

Comment: I suspected it was a lack in my understanding. Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually, it is a complicated issue.  Let's say that the company founder is known as _Bill_ to the employees but prefers _William_ when the name is shown in the director listing.  It might be nice to have explicit implementations of `Employee.GetName` and `Director.GetName`.  C# allows explicit interface implementations, but it won't allow explicit implementations of interfaces one back in the inheritance chain.  If, for example, both employee and director had `GetPicture` declared, then a class could implement `Employee.GetPicture` and `Director.GetPicture`, but not `Employee.GetAge`

Comment: This, by the way, bit me sometime in the last month - I can't remember what the issue was.  The solution was a complete Kludge

Comment: @Flydog57 I am not sure if explicit interface implementation is supported in TS yet

Answer (score 1):

Why is the director not receiving a salary? Director is an employee which in turn naturally is a person.

```
public interface Director : Employee {
    int GetSharesHeld();
}

public interface CompanyFounder : Director {
    string GetReasonStartedCompany();
}
```

Comment: Because a non executive director extends director but not employee. The interfaces maps the org structure. Like the CompanyFounder , a FinanceDirector would extend Director and Employee. Aside from all this, I have recently been working with Omit and Pick in Typescript and they actually solve the problem in a different non traditional OOP way.